# CakePHP 2 progressive loading with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, pagination

I want to use progressive loading in CakePHP 2 instead of pagination. Is there any good tutorial for this? I searched on google but I cannot find anything that can help me. Maybe I did not use the right keywords or has another name?

Comment: Please limit to questions on actual programming related problems. Keywords for your google search: **lazy loading**, **infinite scrolling**, **endless pages**, etc

Comment: This jQuery plugin could help you: <http://plugins.jquery.com/ias/>

Comment: **Infinite Ajax Scroll** http://plugins.jquery.com/ias/